# Exiting a nested foreach (function) loops in javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

i'm trying to check if all the fields in my form, which is needed (isRequired=true) are fulfilled.
i'm doing it by comparing the form structure (assesmentForm) with the user response (which is on the $scope).
i wan't to know some details (starting with VF) about the field and i want it to stop once it found a field which is not fulfilled.
the problem is when i'm using the "return" inside the forEach loop - instead of getting out of the forEach it goes to the next iteration (the next function). i tried using: break, continue, labeling, etc'
i really need some help

```
function checkFieldsValidation () {
        var VFflag =true; //Validation Failed Flag - true: not failed, False - failed
            assessmentForm.Objectives.forEach(function(o){
            if (VFflag){
            o.component.Fields.forEach(function(f){
                if (VFflag){
                    if (f.IsRequired ){
                            for (var i in $scope.responses )
                            {
                                    if( $scope.responses[i].objectives[o.relationship.ActivityRelationshipID][f.FieldID].value.length>0){ 
                                    VFflag=VFflag;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    var VFparIndex=i;
                                    var VFActivityRelationshipID=o.relationship.ActivityRelationshipID;
                                    var VFFieldID = f.FieldID;
                                    VFflag=false;
                                    return;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
                else {return;}
                }
                )
            } else {return;}
            }
            )
        return [VFflag,VFparIndex,VFActivityRelationshipID,VFFieldID];
        }
```

Comment: inside forEach if you return anything except 'false' it continues to loop until it finds no object which indeed returns false. So you need to return false to break the loop

Comment: Hi lombausch. i've tried to returnthe VFflag (which is false) and it still stay in the foreach loop so i guess it is not the answer. thanks any how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Use `.every` instead of `.forEach`.

From [the MDN page on forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> Note : There is no way to stop or break a forEach loop. The solution
>   is to use Array.every or Array.some.

If you use `.every` instead of `.forEach`, you will be able to stop the first time it fails to validate. See that MDN page for more examples, one from the `.every` page:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return (element >= 10);
}
var passed = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);
```

---

--- edit: How to use with objects --

In the comment, you asked how to do this with objects, as you have done with `o` and `f` in your example.

Currently you are defining the anonymous function

```
function(o){ .... }
```

to use in the loop. This means the `forEach` call is receiving that function, and for each item in the array it calls the function with the current array item as the argument.

In the example above, the same is happening; let's do it more simply:

```
var numbers = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44];
var allValid = numbers.every(function(num) { return (num > 10) });
```

This time we are using an anonymous function. The MDN page for `.every` states: "callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed" - they are named `element`, `index` and `array` in the example at the top. Since you only want the current element of the array, just supply one argument name in the function (`function(o)`) instead of three (`function(o, index, array)`). The other two turn out to be very useful if you need to know where you are in the array.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the help - i need to go with objects (in the first is o and in the second is f) - how do i do it in .every? i tried to figure it out and didn't find a good answer for this. thanks!

Comment: @GiladLivnat: I've modified the answer to elaborate. Essentially, you have an anonymous function at the moment (function(o) { ... } doesn't have a name), and you can carry on doing the same.

Comment: @GiladLivnat: Just for future reference, do upvote good answers so that they shuffle to the top! This answer will stay at the top because you've accepted it, but in general it's a good habit to have. Glad to have helped, learnt something new about .every!